# request camera permission only after button is clicked

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

I created an app where I have a place to put profile picture and it looks as follows:

[image]

When the camera button is click there are two options:

[image]

Now, I had like my app to ask the users if they allow me to grant camera permissions once they click on the "Camera" option but I can't figure out how to do it.

Currently, the app asks for permission at the first time the user enters this activity.

How can I make the grant permission to pop up only after this Cemra button is clicked?

My code is:

```
private void showPictureDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {"Photo Gallery", "Camera" };
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            (dialog, which) -> {
                switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        choosePhotoFromGallary();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        takePhotoFromCamera();
                        break;
                }
            } );
    pictureDialog.show();
}
public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, AppConstants.GALLERY);
}

private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap fixBitmap;
    if (requestCode == AppConstants.GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                DOES SOMETHING
            } catch (IOException ignored) {

            }
        }

    } else if (requestCode == AppConstants.CAMERA) {
            DOES SOMETHING
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 5) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where did you put your "request camera permission" code ?

Comment: In the main class ProfileACtivity extends AppCompactActivity, outside of onCreate

Comment: Please check my answer. Hope that help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea for your problem is: **You should request camera permission when user click on "Camera" option on your dialog NOT when the activity is created**.

And below is my solution:

First remove your current "request camera permission" code

```
private void showPictureDialog(){
    ...
                    case 1:
                        checkPermissionAndOpenCamera();
                        break;
    ...
}

/**
 * This will check your app camera permission.
 * If its granted, open camera
 * else request camera permission then open it later.
 */
void checkPermissionAndOpenCamera() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 5);
    } else {
        takePhotoFromCamera();
    }
}


private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 5) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePhotoFromCamera();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It still asked me the moment I entered the activity and not only after I clicked the camera.

Comment: Did you remove your previous camera permission check code ? May I see your full code ?

Comment: From my understanding it should be somewhere in if (requestCode == AppConstants.CAMERA)

Comment: I don't think that is our problem :) Cause the `onActivityResult` is only called after your camera is opened and finish taken picture or cancelled.

Comment: Can you update your `onCreate` function code. I think that will lead to your issue :)

Comment: My bad mate, your code works perfect, i had a line that caused a problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For requesting permissions I use great library Dexter from Karumi:

https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

I have the same case as you, and what I do is simply this:

```kotlin
txt_choose_from_gallery.setOnClickListener {
    checkPhotoPermissions {
        choosePictureFromGallery()
    }
}

txt_take_picture.setOnClickListener {
    checkPhotoPermissions {
        takePictureWithCamera()
    }
}

private fun checkPhotoPermissions(onPermissionGranted: () -> Unit) {
        Dexter.withActivity(activity)
            .withPermissions(
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            )
            .withListener(object : BaseMultiplePermissionsListener() {
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(response: MultiplePermissionsReport) {
                    if (response.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        onPermissionGranted()
                    }
                }
            })
            .check()
    }
```

You can easily use convert it to Java, just change the higher order function `onPermissionGranted: () -> Unit` to interface, so you have for example:

```java
interface OnPermissionGrantedListner {
    void onPermissionGranted();
}

private void checkPhotoPermission(OnPermissionGrantedListener listener) {
    // Dexter code for checking permission, invoke listener in overridden onPermissionChecked method in BaseMultiplePermissionsListener
    listener.onPermissionGranted()
}

private void showPictureDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {"Photo Gallery", "Camera" };
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            (dialog, which) -> {
                switch (which) {
                    case 0:
                        checkPhotoPermission(new OnPermissionGrantedListener {
                            @Override
                            void onPermissionGranted() {
                                choosePhotoFromGallery();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        checkPhotoPermission(new OnPermissionGrantedListener {
                            @Override
                            void onPermissionGranted() {
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                            }
                        }                            
                        break;
                }
            } );
    pictureDialog.show();
}
```